# selenium метод add_cookie() загружает на сайт только cookie с параметром priority: medium, high-priority cookies - нет

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

Я через инструменты разработчика скопировал с главной страницы сайта https://kad.arbitr.ru/ все cookies, среди них cookies со значением атрибута priority: High, поместил их в xlsx-документ, достал в их в скрипте в список словарей cookies. Далее:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://kad.arbitr.ru/")
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

После этого во всё ещё открытом вебдрайвером браузере открываю инструменты разработчика и не вижу там всех cookies, которые хранились в списке cookies, все они были со значением атрибута priority: Medium,
а тех, что имеют значение атрибута priority: High, там не было. Вследствие этого искать информацию на сайте я не мог, т.к. кнопка поиска попросту не работала.

Как загрузить на сайт все cookies?

Comment: я заметил, что дело скорее не в приоритете, а в именах, т.к. если я даже вручную заменю приоритет cookies'ов с High на Medium, они по прежнему не будут отображаться.

Comment: В словари свои добавь поле с доменом.

Comment: Оно там есть, но результата нет, сайт мне 451 ошибку выдаёт :/